# SELECT statement from Oracle database in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, wcf

I've been working on creating a wcf service that will connect to and run a query on an Oracle database and return the data. I'm trying to learn how to use a select statement within my code to return data from the database and thus far, I'm lost as where to even start. I've found the BizTalk adapter for Oracle here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788454.aspx

Is that something I should be using to do simple select statements on the Oracle database or is there a better method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Entity Framework with LINQ to Entities. Read more for  [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)

[and Oracle Data Access Components for .Net](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html)

You can also use [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)

Some sample usage of [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-mar/o24odp-2147205.html)